# How to specify a CPU core to run a program in Linux

Tags: linux, process, multicore

I need to run two programs on the same core of a CPU. The second one always runs on another core because the first program uses 50% of the first core. How can I force Linux to run a program on a core?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
schedtool -a 0x1 -e program1
schedtool -a 0x1 -e program2
```

See the [schedtool manual](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/3629368/numer/8/nazwa/schedtool) for details.

Comment: As i can see, this tool sets affinity of already running process (or am i wrong?). I need some tool to be able to start process on the determined CPU core.

Comment: No, it allows to start processes using `-e` flag. Oops, missed the flag in my example, now fixed.